# TeamCity local artifacts path pattern

Tags: teamcity

I want to create automatic upload to ftp, using 'FTP Upload' runner, with different build configuration, which depends on successfull build of main configuration. But the thing is I don't know the pattern. As for now path looks like this:

```
C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\system\artifacts\<project_name>\<build config name>\528
```

What variable contains this last number?

Comment: Is the last number not the `%system.build.number%`?

Comment: no, I've been experimenting with this for several hours on friday and now today.
Maybe a good idea is to call common build parameter or something? I am a bit new to configuring CI/CD servers, so I cannot think of better approach

Comment: @DmytroBukanov please give more details on what you are trying to achieve. Referencing the `<TeamCity_Data_Directory>\system\artifacts` does not feel right, as the `FTP Upload` runner is executed on Build Agent (which in most cases is separate machine) and expects paths relative to agent's working directory.

Comment: The situation in general lloks like this:
I have to store artifacts on FTP. FTP is on the same machine as TC server and agent (don't ask me why). So I have to somehow grab artifacts and put them into  ftp://"project"/msi and ftp://"project"/nuget, depending on build configuration. 
I've tried:
1. Grabbing artifacts directly - from folder shown in the initial post, idea failed
2. Now I've settled separate build configuration 'FTP transfer' with artifact dependency from build, which produces artifacts. Now I need to learn how to use that dependency to upload files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with bad description of my problem, more definiteve one:
 I have to store artifacts on FTP. FTP is on the same machine as TC server and agent (don't ask me why). So I have to somehow grab artifacts and put them into ftp://"project"/msi and ftp://"project"/nuget, depending on build configuration. I've tried: Grabbing artifacts directly - from folder shown in the initial post, idea failed.

The solution is to create another build configuration and set Artifact dependencies, this makes artifacts reachable from new build configuration, which allows to use FTP Upload runner.

Thanks everyone!